# Cannot Understand this JavaScript Construct

Tags: javascript

Below I have attached an excerpt from the chapter 10 of Eloquent JavaScript book.

```
var dayName = function () {
    var names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
    ];
    return function (number) {
        return names[number];
    };
}(); //==> '();' this construct right here....

console.log(dayName(3));
```

What I cannot understand is why this function has a trailing **();**?

What is it's use? I have tried finding the answer but I don't know what to look for.

Can anybody explain me why this construct is added in the end? Any help would be invaluable.

Comment: @Tushar But isnt it called here @ "console.log(dayName(3));"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the function immediately and assign the returned value to the variable.

```
var name = function() {
    // Function body
}();
```

In your case, the function returns another function. Thus, the function `dayName` is the returned function having access to the `names` variable.

The inner function is **[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)** and thus have access to the outer function variables.

In other words, the function is

```
var dayName = function (number) {
    return names[number];
};
```

with having access to the *private variable* `names`.

Also see

1. [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)
2. [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)